# Syntax error: java doesn't recognize a method

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax

I have imported all classes.

Here at sendMessage i recieve the error: void is an invalid type of the variable sendMessage.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    public void sendMessage(View view){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not declare a method within another method. Close the curly bracket of `onCreate` before starting to declare the `sendMessage` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}// close onCreate method first

public void sendMessage(View view){
}
```

A java class is structured like this:

- package

  - class

    - field
    - method

      - no method declaration allowed within another method
    - (inner classes)